# @ConfiguredJsonCodec doesn't work with additional constructor

Tags: scala, configuration, circe

```
import io.circe.generic.extras.{Configuration, ConfiguredJsonCodec}
@ConfiguredJsonCodec case class Foo(firstName: String)
object Foo {
implicit val snakeConfiguration=Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames}
```

after parsing

```
{"first_name":"Bob"}
```

we get

```
Foo("Bob")
```

If we add to Foo additional empty constructor

```
@ConfiguredJsonCodec case class Foo(firstName: String) {
def this() = this("")
}
object Foo {implicit val
 snakeConfiguration=Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames}
```

we will get

```
could not find Lazy implicit value of type io.circe.generic.extras.decoding.ConfiguredDecoder[Foo]
```

Please, help me to fix that error

Comment: This looks like it may be a bug (whether in circe or Shapeless I can't tell yet). Is there a reason you don't want to use a default argument for `firstName` instead of overloading the constructor?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. I don't want to use a default argument for firstName because these classes are used for jaxb and jaxb needs no-arg constructor in some cases

Comment: For the record, this is a Shapeless bug, but we might eventually work around it in circe: https://github.com/circe/circe/issues/1129#issuecomment-494358743